# When I try and boot my SSH server, it shows [nodename nor servname provided, or not known], What do I do?

Tags: ios, ipad, ssh

On (I think) Wednesday, January 22, I launched termius, an iOS ssh server client and host app.

As I read the manual to make a host, it said to tap the host when the settings are set, but then, an error appeared and halted the program to make a host. The error said:

> Connection could not established:
>
> nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Here’s a screenshot of the error:

[image: me while I try booting it up]

I did not know what to do so I first consulted the manual. Then googled about 5 times, and then went to ask a question here. I searched everywhere for an answer for this problem but I came up with nothing.

Anyways, I push start over a couple of times but still came with the same response. I reinstalled the app, same thing, I made a new host, same thing, new account, same thing.

How can I resolve this problem?

P.S. My system specs are a iPad Pro on software version: 13.3

Comment: Is *James Server* a valid and working ssh server? Try to connect to this address: *test.rebex.net* user: *demo* password: *password* and try again. This host is a working (just tested!) ssh test server.

Comment: I have connected to that specific server before to use SFTP on it to see the png files and worked fine. I don’t know why it’s doing this to me if I read the manual.

Comment: Accessing an SFTP server successfully doesn't necessarily mean that you can also connect via SSH. In OpenSSH you may allow access to SFTP but deny SSH with a    server-side config.

Comment: Now I’m not really sure but I think termius uses open ssh so I guess that’s a clue to this error

Comment: Anyone going to respond?

Comment: What's the address of *James Server* (something like *test.rebex.net* or an IP address)? I will test it with a command line ssh client...

Comment: Here, I couldn’t find the exact link but here’s some pictures: https://imgur.com/a/VSzFYDS

Comment: oh btw can you move this to chat

Comment: Hello? Anyone still here?